# Convert shaders from blender to glsl shaders and vice versa

Tags: node-editor, shaders, shader-nodes, glsl

**Convert shaders from blender to glsl shaders and vice versa**. I have a ready-made glsl project and would like to find a way to transfer them to blender, I saw a demand through node script, maybe there is another way. And is it also possible to get the code from the blender shader in glsl code ?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures/57541